# Blazor Web Assembly not downloading dlls

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have just started with Blazor and following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN1ffDrdYds).

It shows that the dlls are downloaded in the client side. [Video timestamp 5:31]

But when I run the sample application in my local, there are no dlls downloaded.  Has anything changed. Or am I missing something here like enabling any setting in the browser.

Using chrome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

304 only means that the resources doesn't need to be retransmitted, it uses what is found in the cache:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304

Empty your cache and restart, you should then see a 20x for those files.

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP was referring to the lack of any `.dll` files in the Network tab -- not about the 304s for the blazor JS file.

Comment: You might be right?

Comment: In that case, I think you are right but I still think its related to caching. If the dlls didn't change, it won't show in the network tab

Comment: Disabling cache in the browser console, did not work. But when I browse the page in incognito it worked and loaded all the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The problem was that the server where I have the application hosted has a application firewall and it was blocking the dlls download. If you have Plesk panel, under websites and domains, choose your domain or subdomain and select "Web Application Firewall" and disable it.